# How to solve system of trigonometric equations in Maxima CAS?

Tags: trigonometry, curve, ellipse, maxima, equation-solving

I want to find equation of scaled ( smaller) [ellipse inscribed in another ellipse with 2 common points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Adam_majewski/sandbox#scaled)

I have system of 2 trigonometric equations ( eq1 and eq2) and 2 variables:

- s ( it is a scaling factor of second ellipse) s = a'/a
- t ( it is a parameter of ellipse )

```
kill(all);
remvalue(all);
ratprint:false;
numer:true$


GivePointOfEllipse(a,b, t):= a*cos(t) + b*sin(t)*%i$


/* trigonometric functions in Maxima CAS use radians */
deg2rad(t):= float(t*2*%pi/360)$


theta :deg2rad(30) $  /* theta is the angle between    */
a:3$
b:2$


z1: GivePointOfEllipse(a, b, t)$



/* */
x1:realpart(z1)$
y1:imagpart(z1)$

/* system of 2 trigonometric equations */
eq1: x1 = s*a*cos(t)*cos(theta) - s*b*sin(t) * sin(theta)$
eq2: y1 = s*a*cos(t)*sin(theta) + s*b*sin(t) * cos(theta)$
```

I can solve it using solve:

```
 solvetrigwarn: false$
sol:solve([eq1,eq2],[s,t])$
```

but it gives no result ( empty list). So I use solver:

```
load(Solver)$
ss:Solver([eq1,eq2],[s,t])$
```

It gives some result, the relation between s and t:

```
ss;

(%o37) [[s = -(42978006*cos(t))/(14326002*sin(t)-37220045*cos(t)),
         [(28652004*sin(t)^2+64467009*cos(t)^2)
           /(14326002*sin(t)-37220045*cos(t))]]]
```

so I check it :

```
fs(t):=  42978006*cos(t)/( 14326002*sin(t) -37220045*cos(t));
 plot2d (fs(t), [t, 0, 2*%pi])$
 
fs2(t):=(28652004 *(sin (t))^2 + 64467009*(cos(t))^2)/ (14326002*sin(t)-37220045* cos(t))$
  plot2d (fs2(t), [t, 0, 2*%pi])$
```

but the result is not good:
[image]

I think that s should be a positive number smaller then 1. For example

- for theta = 30 degrees s = 0.8117
- for theta = 5 degrees s = 0.942

Value of parameter t is not important here.

How can I do it ?
TIA

Comment: I don't know if Maxima can find a symbolic solution for those equations. My advice at this point is to try for a numerical approximation. You can try `mnewton`; I think there is also a package derived from Fortran for solving equations, although I forget what it is named. Try looking in maxima/share. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: @Robert Dodier Thx. I'm lazy so I took formula from the other question. The result : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Nested_Ellipses.png